# How is Docker different from a normal OS process?

Tags: process, virtual-machine, virtualization, docker

There is a question [How is Docker.io different from a normal virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-io-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine), where an answer goes into details describing how lightweight Docker is and how isolated it is. I am trying to understand:

1. How is Docker different from a regular OS process?
2. What benefitы does it provide on top of a separate OS process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dotCloud did a series of articles talking about how containers build on OS namespaces and groups. They were called [Under the Hood](http://blog.dotcloud.com/under-the-hood-linux-kernels-on-dotcloud-part) and while they were focused on the dotCloud PaaS, the general principles apply to all container systems.

So in the big picture, Docker processes are exactly regular OS processes. They just set some extra parameters (namespaces, cgroups, filesystem mounts) that are normally left to default values.

When you set these values to non-default parameters, you get additional isolation for your new process and more control over resources they use.