# Why do I need a container base image like BusyBox, Alpine and JDK If my host OS is Linux and It has JDK in it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker technology and I did my research according to my question. There are few similar questions like these:

[What is the relationship between the docker host OS and the container base image OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786209/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-docker-host-os-and-the-container-base-image)

[Host-based-containers vs image-based-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655050/host-based-containers-vs-image-based-containers)

[I thought I understood Docker until I saw the BusyBox docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291458/i-thought-i-understood-docker-until-i-saw-the-busybox-docker-image)

[Why do you need a base image with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274162/why-do-you-need-a-base-image-with-docker)

but I still don't understand should I use base image OS or base image JDK if I have a Linux host OS with JDK installed.

I was checking some Dockerfiles of official images on DockerHub and I saw lines like `FROM ubuntu`, `FROM alpine`, `FROM openjdk:8-jdk` and I don't understand why is it necessary?

I have read something about isolation or encapsulation for filesystem in container. Maybe they are used to specify container specific environment variables or arguments for Java or OS.

I will be grateful for any explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, what's running inside the container has no access to files in the host OS. That is the point of using a container: isolation. If you have a Java installation in the host OS, and you mount that as a volume when you run the container, processes inside the container might be able to use that as their Java, but that would generally be a *terrible, terrible* bad practice.

Comment: I think a good followup question to that is "why is isolation important?"