# Understanding docker container processes

Tags: docker, process

Sorry if this is a silly question, but:

I came from vagrant where we have a full featured OS in each machine, where running `ps -aux` we can see the OS processes and our services (I know to some extent the difference between applications running in VMs and Docker).

Then I've just built some containers using docker-compose and logged in into a container using bash (which is based on debian:jessie image). After running `ps -aux`I can only see the services I installed, not a single OS's process. Why? Where they are? How this works?

Docker has a VM in which the containers run, each container may be based on a different distribution, so, is the OS containerized also, giving the fact the there's the host's OS (VM) for docker?

Comment: Whenever you hear "Docker container", just think "normal process, but with a bunch of things (filesystem, processes, network stuff, etc.) sandboxed via namespacing".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So actually the debian:jessie docker's image is not an OS but a simulation of it in a single process?

Comment: Basically, all you're getting is a filesystem that looks like the filesystem on a "real" Jessie system (on top of the standard Docker functionality - sandboxed networks, etc.)  There's no emulation/simulation going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Docker has a VM in which the containers run

Nope, containers are not VMs (docker includes a VM for desktop versions, but that isn't a container, and there are VM runtimes, but that's not a traditional container).

Containers are a way to isolate a running application with kernel namespaces for things like the filesystem, pids, and network. They all run in the same kernel. Pulling a base image for Alpine, Ubuntu, etc, gives you the base filesystem, libraries, package managers, but not the kernel. The only process launched inside a container is your application, and when your application exits, so does the container. Therefore you won't see OS utilities running.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784145/596285)