# Docker containers python environment vs python virtual environments

Tags: python, docker, containers, virtual, environment

I program primarily in python and have some experience with **virtual environments**. I am new to the software and started looking at docker to run my code. I would like insight on what it does and how it works.

From my understanding **docker containers are like virtual environments** that run a set of instructions when executed and can treat that everything contained within it as a single entity (so it or something else wouldn't be conditional on each other?). As I read more about containers, they sound pretty perfect and would **eliminate any need for virtual environments** but again unsure. Would much appreciate some clarification on this because I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: Check their 101 series, it's pretty good https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial. Also, if you want to understand at a deeper level, watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fi7uSYlOdc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker, what is it and what is the purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089344/docker-what-is-it-and-what-is-the-purpose)

Comment: Docker's isolation environment also separates the host's local filesystem from the container's filesystem; this is a problem for many typical applications.  If you're actively developing, this isolation also means the container has a separate filesystem from your IDE, which gets inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the python virtual environment is the **isolation** of the environment for each project, it's mean that **each project can have its own dependencies, regardless of what dependencies every other project has**.

[image]

[what-is-a-virtual-environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#what-is-a-virtual-environment)

But when it comes to docker, you can treat **each docker image as an isolated environment**, you do not need to create or maintain a virtual environment in Dockerfile, as Dockerfile should be base on a particular version of python and should run single project.

[image]

[python-versions-docker](https://realpython.com/python-versions-docker/)

So in short, if you have 3 projects that require

- Project A requires Python 3.6
- Project B requires Python 3.7
- Project C requires Python 3.8

All need to chose base image for each project

- Project A `FROM python:3.6`
- Project B `FROM python:3.7`
- Project C `FROM python:3.8`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think of containers as a OS on top of your OS. You can google lots of info about docker, but if talking in simple language it is a thin layer that runs on top of your OS, uses your OS's resources (unlike VM), and runs its own enclosed environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not any of the two can replace the other. It depends on what you are doing.

Python virtual environment is a way to encapsulate all app dependencies inside a single environment (actually a directory). These dependencies are other apps and packages that support the OS version you are using.

Docker container is a way to run a virtual machine with low resource consumption by sharing a lot of your OS files (more details in docker docs)

So,

if you need to create a development environment; it is recommended to use docker because you can douplicate the exact development experience for all developpers. Everything will be in a virtual machine that has its own OS version and its own files (virtually). Python virtual envirounment will not 100% help other developers unless they are using the same OS version of yours and they can duplicate your exact steps to deploy your app

But, if you are creating a package that will deploy a remote server (let say by using ansible), docker will be an extra un-needed step. Python environment will do the job just fine without any issue.

Also, it is very common to have dockers that include many python virtual environments; one environment for each service. So, even a docker image can include a python venv

Comment: Ok wow, thank you. Is it that docker is heavier and I should opt for python virtual environments whenever I can?

Comment: So far, I've found that Docker completely replaces my need to create virtual environments.