# How is Docker advantageous for multi-application or micro-service architecture

Tags: linux, docker, architecture, microservices, devops

I'm trying to understand Docker and how it solves rollout issues and aids in continuous deployment. We have a product comprising of 4 Java applications, 1 Python application, 1 NodeJs, 1 DB (shared), RMQ (shared) and Apache (shared). All the applications run on a dedicated Linux machine. Today, the Java applications are built into rpm packages and deployed. We use Git to deploy Python and NodeJS applications. Open-JDK, Python, DB, RMQ and Apache are installed on the OS machine. When we need to deploy a new application, we either just do Git pull or deploy a new rpm. The setup works fine.

From what I understand, the best practice is to have each process running in isolated containers. So, in all the product would have 9 containers. 4 of which have to be built on open-jdk images. It all seems complicated and maybe a bit overkill.

How does a Docker setup help in our architecture. Whatever it claims to solve, is already a simple process to being with. So why use Docker and add it our software maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

Docker is a tool designed to make it easier to create, deploy, and run applications by using containers. Containers allow a developer to package up an application with all of the parts it needs, such as libraries and other dependencies, and deploy it as one package.

See more here: [More about docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089344/docker-what-is-it-and-what-is-the-purpose)

The main usages of docker in your case would be:

- Scalability
- Devops (CI/CD)

Answer (score 0):

Whether microservices and containerisation is beneficial to you will be heavily dependant on your development teams and how they are structured. If you have a small development team that works on the complete monolith at present and you have no plans to change that, microservices will have little benefit. Conversely, if you are looking to increase the size of the dev team or have a dev team who already specialise in specific areas of business logic, microservices could make the software delivery process quicker and more efficient.

With containerisation, development can be done in a more isolated, less risky manner depending how isolated/loosely coupled/inter dependant the microservices are. Different microservices can be developed and delivered without fear of effecting other areas of business logic which then leads to quicker CI/CD cycles.

Containerisation CAN also reduce resource costs. Since each service is running in a further abstracted layer from the os, you are able to have further control over what runs where and how much resource is committed to that service. As the application scales, horizontal and vertical scaling can be made a lot easier using orchestration engines such as Kubernetes.

In short, it all depends on how complex your application is at present, how your development team is structures and how you are looking to move forward in the future.