# Docker and Splash to render website does not work

Tags: docker, splash-screen

I am starting out with Linux(Ubuntu) + docker. See http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/install.html#linux-docker

- Installed docker
- Pulled the scrapinghub/splash (what does this do??)

  Can you please help me understand what actually happens when I run command
  `sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash` ?
  Because I was using this and the splash rendered **no page at all**. Not even google.com (which it suggests on the main page). There was a constant timeout error. I increased the `max-timeout 3600` at starting docker but it did not work.
  The FAQ here http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/faq.html says "Splash instance could be overloaded". What splash instance. Am I not using a local version over here? It might be a naive question but I can't just get it to work for any website.

Now I am going to try the Ubuntu manual version. (Doing the installations right now. Will let you know the outcome. But what would this option do?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16048358/3068807 This is what docker is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was facing this issue I posted these on github:

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/36

https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/394

My connection speed was 1Mbps. I changed the internet connection to 5 Mbps and it solved the issue (for me at least). I have mentioned this in the last comment of second link.

In second link see how my system was configured.