# What is the overhead of using docker on windows, since I still have to download virtualbox

Tags: windows, docker, overhead

I am trying to build several components in docker who have indirect or direct dependencies after which I have to perform testing.I am using windows as my OS and have installed docker in that. What is the overhead of using docker on windows, since I still have to download virtualbox.

Comment: I believe this might be of help to u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine

Comment: Yes. i have read this. Thanks, I was looking for a little precise numbers about the overhead. If you come across something like that, do let me know.