# Should docker instances be used on a big VM or on multiple VMs?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, lxc

Assuming I have a docker image of the following:

```
-Centos (base image)
-Tomcat
-MySQL
```

Now assume this image will be used by multiple customers/companies. Do I run different instances on a big VM for each client or create a small VM for each customer and run the docker image on it?

I already have scripts to install these services on a given VM so using docker sounds kind of pointless. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can do either, depends on what level of isolation you want. You can always start with a big VM and move to smaller ones later, that is what is great about docker, moving things around is easier, as well as giving you the option to run multi tenant or not.

Comment: but my question is, if I already have .sh files to install services on a VM automatically, what would be the need for docker?

Comment: This question has been answered a number of times. Feel free to visit the docker website http://www.docker.com or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine

Comment: I have actually red most of these posts, but question remains. From the way it looks, docker is mainly used to create "disposable test environments", no so much as a production environment.

Comment: If you would read the information on the docker website, you can see it is for much more than that, and many many people are using this in production today and for than just testing. Since all that stuff is already covered elsewhere it doesn't make sense to post it again here.

Comment: Docker really shines with tools like Kubernetes or DC/OS. You should read about them.