# Docker OS / application containers

Tags: docker, containers

Im trying to understand how Docker works , in the documentation i found that Docker supports only Application containers and not OS containers. However, im able for example to run an Ubuntu 14.04 image using Docker. Does it mean that Ubuntu 14.04 image is not an OS container ? if not, can anyone explain to me what is a OS container .
thank you

Comment: What documentation described OS and Application containers? And why weren't they defined properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Docker different from a normal virtual machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1):

OS is a software,other application also is a software.They are not difference in essence.

OS = kernel + FileSYStem/software repository and so on

so there is no so called OS containers , only CONTAINER ,share kernel with the host OS,if you run an OS, you can image you run a software(not the kernel) on your host OS kernel!

your OS only contain the other part but no kernel