# What is the difference between running software in a Docker container Vs Real OS

Tags: linux, docker

This question is from a perspective of OS kernel, dependencies and customizations a distro might have, since docker containers shares the host OS kernel, just that perform isolation on it's resources and allow to use say from an Ubuntu host OS a docker container running CentOS.

What would be the differences or "to-keep-in-mind" details when running software directly in a host OS vs a docker container?

The use case and context is that, say you want to certify your software runs ok on a certain distro, say CentOS, then you fire up a docker container with this as base image but running in an Ubuntu OS as Host. Would it be significant differences between this setup VS running the software/tests directly on a host installed CentOS?.

Comment: Possibly helpful, though not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine

Comment: Competing processes within the OS and your app,  networking issues and user access rights are the first things I can think of that would be different between containers and bare metal