# How many containers should exist per host in production? How should services be split?

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to understand the benefits of Docker better and I am not really understanding how it would work in production.

Let's say I have a web frontend, a rest api backend and a db. That makes 3 containers.

Let's say that I want 3 of the front end, 5 of the backend and 7 of the db. (Minor question: Does it ever make sense to have less dbs than backend servers?)

Now, given the above scenario, if I package them all on the same host then I gain the benefit of efficiently using the resources of the host, but then I am DOA when that machine fails or has a network partition.

If I separate them into 1 full application (ie 1 FE, 1 BE & 1 DB) per host, and put extra containers on their own host, I get some advantages of using resources efficiently, but it seems to me that I still lose significantly when I have a network partition since it will take down multiple services.

Hence I'm almost leaning to the conclusion that I should be putting in 1 container per host, but then that means I am using my resources pretty inefficiently and then what are the benefits of containers in production? I mean, an OS might be an extra couple gigs per machine in storage size, but most cloud providers give you a minimum of 10 gigs storage. And let's face it, a rest api backend or a web front end is not gonna even come close to the 10 gigs...even including the OS.

So, after all that, I'm trying to figure out if I'm missing the point of containers? Are the benefits of keeping all containers of an application on 1 host, mostly tied to testing and development benefits?

I know there are benefits from moving containers amongst different providers/machines easily, but for the most part, I don't see that as a huge gain personally since that was doable with images...

Are there any other benefits for containers in production that I am missing? Or are the main benefits for testing and development? (Am I thinking about containers in production wrong)?

Comment: According to me, docker brings me simple deployment on production and localhost. With one time setup I can run all containers with one command. That was an another benefit. But I see you stuck at zero downtime clustering with your containers but nothing to worry about it, docker has some methods and configurations about that. Your approaches and thoughts seems okay.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Note**: The question is very broad and could fill an entire book but I'll shed some light.

### Benefits of containers

The exciting part about containers is not about their use on a single host, but their use across hosts connected on a large cluster. Do not look at your machines as independent docker hosts, but as a pool of resource to host your containers.

Containers alone are not ground-breaking (*ie.* Docker's CTO stating at the last *DockerCon* that *"nobody cares about containers"*), but coupled to state of the art schedulers and container orchestration frameworks, they become a very powerful abstraction to handle production-grade software.

As to the argument that it also applies to Virtual Machines, yes it does, but containers have some technical advantage (See: [How is Docker different from a normal virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine)) over VMs that makes them convenient to use.

#### On a Single host

On a single host, the benefits you can get from containers are (amongst many others):

- Use as a development environment mimicking the behavior on a real production cluster.
- Reproducible builds independent of the host (convenient for sharing)
- Testing new software without bloating your machine with packages you won't use daily.

#### Extending from a single host to a pool of machines (cluster)

When time comes to manage a production cluster, there are two approaches:

- Create a couple of docker hosts and run/connect containers together "manually" through scripts or using solutions like docker-compose. Monitoring the lifetime of your services/containers is at your charge, and you should be prepared to handle service downtime.
- Let a container orchestrator deal with everything and monitor the lifetime of your services to better cope with failures.

There are plenty of container orchestrators: *Kubernetes*, *Swarm*, *Mesos*, *Nomad*, *Cloud Foundry*, and probably many others. They power many large-scale companies and infrastructures, like Ebay, so they sure found a benefit in using these.

#### Pick the right replication strategy

A container is better used as a **disposable resource** meaning you can stop and restart the DB independently and it shouldn't impact the backend (other than throwing an error because the DB is down). As such you should be able to handle any kind of network partition as long as your services are **properly replicated across several hosts**.

You need to pick a proper **replication strategy**, to make sure your service stays up and running. You can for example replicate your DB across Cloud provider Availability Zones so that when an entire zone goes down, your data remains available.

Using Kubernetes for example, you can put each of your containers (1 FE, 1 BE & 1 DB) in a pod. Kubernetes will deal with replicating this pod on many hosts and monitor that these pods are always up and running, if not a new pod will be created to cope with the failure.

If you want to mitigate the effect of network partitions, specify **node affinities**, hinting the scheduler to place containers on the same subset of machines and replicate on an appropriate number of hosts.

#### How many containers per host?

It really depends on the number of machines you use and the resources they have.

The rule is that you shouldn't bloat a host with too many containers if you don't specify any resource constraint (in terms of CPU or Memory). Otherwise, you risk compromising the host and exhaust its resources, which in turn will impact all the other services on the machine. A good replication strategy is not only important at a single service level, but also to ensure good health for the pool of services that are sharing a host.

Resource constraint should be dealt with depending on the type of your workload: a DB will probably use more resources than your Front-end container so you should size accordingly.

As an example, using Swarm, you can explicitely specify the number of CPUs or Memory you need for a given service (See [docker service documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/)). Although there are many possibilities and you can also give an upper bound/lower bound in terms of CPU or Memory usage. Depending on the values chosen, the scheduler will pin the service to the right machine with available resources.

Kubernetes works pretty much the same way and you can specify limits for your pods (See [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/)).

Mesos has more fine grained resource management policies with frameworks (for specific workloads like Hadoop, Spark, and many more) and with over-commiting capabilities. Mesos is especially convenient for Big Data kind of workloads.

### How should services be split?

It really depends on the orchestration solution:

- In Docker Swarm, you would create a service for each component (FE, BE, DB) and set the desired replication number for each service.
- In Kubernetes, you can either create a pod encompassing the entire application (FE, BE, DB and the volume attached to the DB) or create separate pods for the FE, BE, DB+volume.

Generally: use one service per type of container. Regarding groups of containers, evaluate if it is more convenient to scale the entire group of container (as an atomic unit, ie. a pod) than to manage them separately.

### Sum up

Containers are better used with an orchestration framework/platform. There are plenty of available solutions to deal with container scheduling and resource management. Pick one that might fit your use case, and learn how to use it. Always pick an appropriate replication strategy, keeping in mind possible failure modes. Specify resource constraints for your containers/services when possible to avoid resource exhaustion which could potentially lead to bringing a host down.

Comment: Hi @abronan, can you advise on why Kubernetes breaks (no response from `kubectl`) when I have too many Pods running in the cluster (1000 pods)? There are more than enough resources, so it seems to me that some kind of controller is breaking and unable to handle the amount of Pods.

Answer (score 2):

**Minor question: Does it ever make sense to have less dbs than backend servers?**

Yes.

Consider cases where you hit normal(without many joins) SQL select statements to get data from the database but your Business Logic demands too much computation. In those cases you might consider keeping your Back-End Service count high and Database Service count low.

It all depends on the use case which is getting solved.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of application you run in your containers. From the top of my head I can think of a couple different ways to look at this:

- is your application diskspace heavy?
- do you need the application fail save on multiple machines?
- can you run multiple different instance of different applications on the same host without decreasing performance of them?
- do you use software like [kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) or [swarm](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-swarm) to handle your machines?

I think most of the question are interesting to answer even without containers. Containers might free you of thinking about single hosts, but you still have to decide and measure the load of your host machines yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The number of containers per host depends on the design ratio of the host and the workload ratio of the containers.  Both ratios are
Throughput/Capacity ratios.  In the old days, this was called E/B for execution/bandwidth. Execution was cpu and banwidth was I/o.  Solutions were said to be cpu or I/o bound.

Today memories are very large the critical factor is usually cpu/nest
capacity.  We describe workloads as cpu intense or nest intense. A useful proxy for nest capacity is the size of highest level cache.  A useful design ratio estimator is (clock x cores)/cache. Fir the same core count the machine with a lower design ratio will hold more containers.  In part this is because the machine with more cache will scale better and see less saturation at higher utilization. By