# what is a docker image? what is it trying to solve?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I understand that it is software shipped in some sort of binary format. In simple terms, what exactly is a `docker-image`? And what problem is it trying to solve? And how is it better than other distribution formats?

As a student, I don't completely get the picture of how it works and why so many companies are opting for it? Even many open source libraries are shipped as docker images.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [How is Docker different from a normal virtual machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16047306/744178)

Comment: A docker image makes sense only as the distribution mechanism of a *container*. By itself it's no better than other distribution formats

Answer (score 1):

To understand the `docker images`, you should better understand the main element of the Docker mechanism the [`UnionFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS).

> Unionfs is a filesystem service for Linux, FreeBSD and NetBSD which
>   implements a union mount for other file systems. It allows files and
>   directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be
>   *transparently overlaid*, forming a single coherent file system.

The `docker images` сonsist of several layers(levels). Each layer is a write-protected filesystem, for every instruction in the `Dockerfile` created own layer, which has been placed over already created. Then the `docker run` or `docker create` is invoked, it make a layer on the top with write persmission(also it has doing a lot of other things). This approach to the distribution of containers is very good in my opinion.

<sub>Disclaimer: 
It is my opinion which I'm found somewhere, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.</sub>