# How do i know my CPU supports Docker?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, ept

What are now Docker cpu requirements for running in Linux, say, Ubuntu and Windows?

Is VT-x/AMD-v is enough or VT-d/AMD-Vi is required too?

Does it require MMU virtualization (Intel's Extended Page Tables (EPT) and Unrestricted Mode, and AMD's Nested Page Tables (NPT) and Rapid Virtualization Indexing (RVI)) like Hyper-V?

Would Xeons with VT-x like 53xx, 54xx run both 32-bit and 64-bit docker images, or just 32-bit or none of them in say, Ubuntu?

May be there is some tool to check for compatibility?

Comment: What host OS and docker version?

Comment: The host OS, as in question, Ubuntu, and current Docker version.
Another OS - Windows +  current Docker version.

Answer (score 5):

[Containers aren't virtual machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine). VT-x is not required to run a container. Docker require's certain Linux kernel features. If you have a Linux system on a 3.10+ kernel and a x86-64 CPU, you can run Docker 17.09+.

[Windows Server containers require](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/system-requirements) Windows Server build 1709, Windows Server 2016 (Core and with Desktop Experience) and Windows 10 Professional and Enterprise (Anniversary Edition) (all 64bit).

If you want to use Hyper-V Containers, which provide more isolation than Windows Server containers, then you will need to meet [Hyper-V's virtualisation requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/system-requirements-for-hyper-v-on-windows).

Comment: Please, tell about Xeons! Would they run OK Docker in Ubuntu?

Comment: Xeons released after about 2006 supported 64 bit. The 53xx and 54xx were released in 2007 and support 64bit.