# How docker container use host OS?

Tags: docker

In every docker tutorial, one of the main advantages of the docker is that docker container use host OS. But if that is true, I don't understand why I need to include OS in the image. For example [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) is image of centOS. I understand that if I want to run centOS in container I must pull this image but where then host OS come? It would be best if someone can point me to some link to read about that because I cannot find appropriate one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Docker uses of the host is actually only the OS's *kernel*.

What you include in the Docker container is not the actual OS (i.e., the kernel), but rather all the files that make up a specific distribution, such as Ubuntu or Fedora, or whatever…

This is also the reason why you can't run Linux containers on Windows and vice-versa (without a VM), because Linux software of course doesn't work with the Windows kernel, and Windows software doesn't work with the Linux kernel.

So, all Docker containers running on a given host share the host OS's kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It actually shares the kernel & required libraries to boot the image from host OS. That's why those images are really small & not like traditional ISO files. It primarily utilizes union file system, cgroups and namespaces to manage the images and containers.

You can give a quick read to below -
https://kjanshair.github.io/2017/07/04/Docker-Containers-vs-System-Processes/
[How is Docker different from a normal virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine)

Comment: https://kjanshair.github.io/2017/07/04/Docker-Containers-vs-System-Processes/ -NOT WORKING