# Does running docker inside a virtual machine makes the dockerized app available to be deploy on all virtual private server?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I'm very interested with Docker, in my learning process I am at the point of deploying my app and managing clusters. I'm wondering if put my dockerized app in a virtual machine would allow me to deploy my app on all (or a great part of) VPS available because of running on a VM and not directly on the host,

any hint would be great, 
thanks

Comment: To me it is not clear what you hope to gain by adding another layer by using a vm

Comment: @Marged thanks, I have seen there is some VPS host that are specifically "Docker compatible", and I would know if, by pushing my dockerized app in a virtual machine, I could deploy my dockerize app in more VPS host, allowing me to have more options for my deployment strategy

Comment: I suffered from the same: VPS that are not compatible with docker. I would not try to add another virtualisation layer to them. Use a provider that supports docker, there are plenty like digitalocean, vultr or scaleway

Comment: okay I see, maybe there is some specific reason that leads you to avoid the VM layer path? it could be interesting to know

Comment: Increased complexity and wasted performance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: To phrase the question differently: If you put your car on a tow truck, you can take your car on any roads that support the tow truck. But why would you want to?