# How can a docker container OS different be from host OS?

Tags: docker

As I can see from docker's architecture at multiple sources including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine), one can see containers have same OS as host OS but different namespaces. But I'm running an image on my docker (mac) with Ubuntu OS. How is this architecturally possible?

And how is this not Virtualization?

Host:

```
sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.3
BuildVersion:   18D109
```

From container:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: On a Mac a virtual machine is in fact involved.

Comment: @DavidMaze and for windows too?? Is docker made natively for linux only? Now I'm starting to get why it takes longer to start docker daemon on mac then linux. holy cow!!!