# What's different between Docker and VM?

Tags: docker

I'm a student who is studying Docker first time and uses to Virtual Machine.
I've understood when I use virtual machines on my laptop, the layer is
Application -> Guest OS -> Hypervisor -> Host OS
and in case of Docker
Application -> Docker Engine -> Host OS

It didn't make me confused, but I found I can connect docker containers' shell. And if I use 'ubuntu image,' container's shell looks like ubuntu's bash shell.
So I'm confused about what's different with VM and container. Both VM and container have each operating system, and I can connect through "SSH" or "docker attach."

What's different with Docker's OS image such as Ubuntu and Guest OS in VM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: [Cgroups, namespaces, and beyond: what are containers made from?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sK5i-N34im8) by Jérôme Petazzoni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker container processes run on the host kernel but VM runs processes in guest kernel.
You can see container processes by executing `ps aux` on host machine.