# Virtualization and Containerization Abstraction Level

Tags: docker, virtualization, abstraction

I am learning Docker and I have searched the differences between Virtualization and Containerization. I understand everything clearly except one thing. How do we say that virtualization brings abstraction to hardware and Containerization brings abstraction to operating system? What is the idea behind this abstraction classification? Can anybody explain me the reason for classifying abstraction level like that for both type?

Comment: I believe that this topic is covered [sufficiently enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine) to treat it as a duplicate.

Comment: Containers are ordinary linux processes, check [this definition](https://twitter.com/jpetazzo/status/1047179436959956992): *"Containers are processes, born from tarballs, anchored to namespaces, controlled by cgroups"*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: I dont ask for the differences and silimarities between these concepts. I only ask for what reason we use these abstraction levels.