# Use cases where you want to use VM over docker

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, hypervisor

From this question, it seems like that docker containers are faster and more light weight then VMs. Are there some use cases that you would want to use a VM over using docker containers? Is process isolation sufficient in all most all uses cases over full isolation?

Reference
[How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: Docker does not support windows containers...

Comment: I've seen IIS containers before https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images

Comment: Two questions down from this: [Is it possible to run Windows 10 docker image with full GUI Desktop functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554738/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-10-docker-image-with-full-gui-desktop-functionalit)  That requires a VM.

Comment: I was hoping for something more in line of process isolation vs full isolation. In the case of GUI, it is possible but maybe not in the roadmap of docker just yet.  https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110