# What is docker machine when using simple docker desktop for Window or Mac

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-desktop

- After research about docker swarm. I know more deeply about docker.
- Before that i just install docker window, create image, run image on container. It 's a bit easy.
- But i now i see docker machine which will host the docker engine. Docker machine may be hosted by virtual box, cloud host, and physical host (is it available for only Linux ? )
- The question is what is docker machine when i just install docker desktop. And what is different from docker machine created by Hyper-V using `docker-machine create -d hyperv vm`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.docker.com/machine/ ?

Comment: Yes, so i thinks docker machine is the word for virtual machine which we need to create to host docker-engine. So if we using docker by install docker desktop, where is docker machine here ?