# Docker multi serivces in a single container

Tags: linux, docker

is it a good practice to create one dockerfile with all needed container ,
ex :

```
1 - FROM ubutnu

2 - RUN apt install php7.4

3 - RUN apt install mysql-server

4 - RUN apt install nginx

5 - RUN apt install openssh-server
......
```

Comment: No ist isn‘t.  One docker should provide one service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bad idea. The principle of containers is one service per one container.

A container is really just a process. You might run 50 different containers on a machine, with very little overhead, and still gain the advantages of isolation for each service.

[A good primer on the inherent differences between containers and VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

the service you are looking for is kubernetes and called pod and/or deployment.

You can put nginx/php in two separate container into the same pod and the mysql-server in another pod.