# How can I clone my Google Cloud Instance so I can download it and host it locally using Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hosting

I have an ubuntu server in Google Cloud which I'd like move completely to host in Docker on my desktop machine. How can I just clone it and download it for local usage on ubuntu using Docker?

Is there a way to install docker on the VM and create an image of the machine which i can import into my local machine?

PS: Docker Noob

Comment: Fundamentally, no, Docker containers and VMs are different enough environments that you can't just import one into another.

Comment: but the server is running on ubuntu and Docker runs on ubuntu, is there no way to create an image of the host system from within docker on ubuntu? Is this not what Docker does?

Comment: That is not what Docker does.  [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine) discusses this in some detail.

Comment: It's often helpful to think of a Docker container as a wrapper around _a single process_.  It doesn't need to run a full init system, or login services, or manage its own networking, or any of the other things a (possibly cloud-hosted) VM does.