# Difference between running docker on Windows and on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, vue.js, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I'm developing an application with this stack (main things): Django, Vuejs.

I write code both from my personal computer which runs Windows and my working one which has Ubuntu.

It used to be working similarly until I decided to upgrade some of the libraries of the frontend of my application from my working laptop (Ubuntu). Everything was working fine and since I run my application with docker-compose, I supposed it would work the same on my Windows computer (since the application is running with Docker..eh...).

I kept working from my pro laptop (Ubuntu) and one day I decided to code from my personal one. And at that moment I realized that the frontend was kinda broken...

The problems are :

1. Hot reload of my vuejs application no longer work when running under docker on Windows (Docker Desktop last version and WSL 2 latest stable release 1.0.0).
2. It takes ages for my application to start under development server (when running `npm run serve`).

Whereas on my Ubuntu laptop it's still smooth and hot reload works.

The thing is that, when upgrading the frontend, I scaffolded a new project with Vue CLI to have a clean structure and dependencies, just reinstalled what I needed and moved my code (it was working..). But now I have no idea what could be the root cause because, again, it's working with my Ubuntu machine !

For more information here is my `package.json`, maybe there is something in it that is well known to cause issues :

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^5.8.55",
    "@tiptap/extension-highlight": "^2.0.0-beta.199",
    "@tiptap/extension-image": "^2.0.0-beta.199",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.199",
    "@tiptap/vue-2": "^2.0.0-beta.199",
    "apexcharts": "^3.26.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "echarts": "^5.3.3",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-echarts": "^6.2.3",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-smooth-dnd": "^0.8.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-dialog": "^2.0.14",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Also here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16.17
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json /frontend/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

And the docker-compose part related to my frontend :

```yaml
frontend:
    container_name: app_dev_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mailhog
      - backend
```

If someone has hints for me to look at, or things I should check,... you are very welcome because I feel a bit lost on this issue. For me running things under Docker should not lead to such problems. If it works on my Ubuntu machine, running my docker-compose application should work on another machine, even if the host is running another operating system. It's the purpose of Docker right ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. Changing the underlining OS may have impact on a container, because containers use the host OS. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132462 I don’t use Windows, but I know that at least in the past there were significant limitations to it compared to Linux. Don’t know the current state.

Comment: So developing with Docker is good only for having a common environment and build process but it's not meant to be 100% working from one dev's computer to another, whichever OS he is running on his machine ?!

Comment: And furthermore Docker on Windows through Docker Desktop uses WSL (AFAIK), which is Ubuntu in my case.