# Chapel container segfaults only when running on Windows

Tags: docker, chapel

I was always under the impression that the beauty of docker is it eliminates the "it runs on my machine" result during deployments. I wrote a Dockerfile, based off the latest Arch Linux container, and successfully built it on a Linux machine. I can run the container with no problems on that Linux machine, but when I download it from my hub onto a Windows machine, I get a segmentation fault.

The specific problem is using the Chapel programming language. All I have is a hello world script that I'm compiling and then executing. I get no errors on the Windows machine during compilation, just during execution.

Script:
`writeln("Hello, world!");`

Compilation and execution:
`chpl hello.chpl -o hello && ./hello`

Error:
`line 30:   441 Segmentation fault      ./hello`

I know there's an official Docker container for Chapel, but I chose to install Chapel manually because of some other tools I want to use with it. Either way, it would be good to understand where I'm not understanding what Docker does and why this break is occurring. Is there a way to see the Dockerfile that the official image used to figure out why my build is breaking?

My original hello world was something like:

```
var num_tasks = 10;
coforall taskID in 1..#num_tasks
{
  writeln("Hello from task# ", taskID);
}
```

so I thought maybe it was just the advanced parallelism features that weren't able to translate well in the container, so I removed that portion from the script and it still failed. These were my environment variables when `make`ing Chapel from source in the Dockerfile:

```
CHPL_HWLOC=none
CHPL_TARGET_CPU=none
CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM=linux64
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: `Is there a way to see the Dockerfile that the official image used to figure out why my build is breaking?` Yes, the official image is based on an open-source Dockerfile. https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/main/Dockerfile If that doesn't work, you can also use the `docker history` command on any image to see what commands were used to create it.

Comment: Linux images can only run on Linux hosts and Windows images can only run on Windows hosts. WSL2 enables you to run Linux images on Windows by running a Linux VM under the covers. Are you using WSL2?

Comment: @HansKilian I'm not, I would've never guessed each OS only built for itself. That's very interesting, thank you

Comment: If you want more information on the differences and on how containers are run, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine